# c++,文字列配列をvector<string>に変換するときの参照がわからない

Tags: c++

関数部の`for`文内の`temp.push_back(&p[i  * w]);`の`&p[i  * w]`の`&`の意味がわかりません。
`&`は参照という意味であることは理解しているのですがなぜ参照するのでしょうか？

また、仮引数の時点で配列は先頭のポインターを渡しているので`char *p`でポインタ変数で受けることは理解していますが、それなのになぜ参照するのでしょうか？解説をお願いしたいです。

```
//--- ２次元配列による文字列の配列をvector<string>に変換 ---//
        vector<string> str2dary_to_vec(char *p, int h, int w)
        {
            vector<string> temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
                //temp.push_back("aaa");
                temp.push_back(&p[i * w]);//ここです。
            return temp;
        }


        int main()
        {
            char a[][5] = { "LISP", "C", "Ada" };       // 配列による文字列の配列


            vector<string> sa = str2dary_to_vec(&a[0][0], 3, 5);
            for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < sa.size(); i++)
                cout << "sa[" << i << "] = " << sa[i] << '\n';



            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: 「参考書で説明がないので」は質問の説明にならないと思います。

Comment: @cubick さん、これはやや厳しすぎるコメントではないでしょうか。参考書は確認してみたということを書いておくことで、「参考書を読んでいるならそれを参考にしてください」などの余計なコメントを避けることができます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w=5なので、5文字づつ進めてその都度、アドレス（ポインタ）をpush_back()しているということです。
&p[i * w]は i行目の文字列の先頭を指すポインタということになりますね。

Answer (score 2):

この場合の「&」はアドレス演算子です。
「&」が修飾する対象の型の記述がないことで判別できます。